# Microsoft Excel and GA

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-analytics

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I exported demographic info from google analytics and the dates, in this case days, are inserted as just only numbers, like it counts the days from start to end but it isn't in order either.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try to transform all values from text to number first, then format cells as date.